# Распознать "send <параметр>" и "wait <задержка>" строки из текстового файла в sh скрипте

Tags: sh

Никак не получается написать скрипт для терминала линукса (.sh файл)
Задача такая:

- нужно считывать строки из файла
- есть два типа строк, в одном указаны параметры для программы, в другом указана задержка
- нужно считать параметр для программы, выполнить программу, затем считать задержку. И так по кругу
- При этом в файле это выглядит так: "send <параметр>" и "wait <задержка>"

Как я продвинулся:

Это пример считывания из файла, но я не понял, как считывать сразу две строки

```
file="data.txt"
while IFS= read line
do
    echo "$line"
    sleep 1
done <"$file"
```

Это что-то вроде парсинга строки, но я не очень разобрался в параметрах этого

```
$first=$(echo $VERSION | cut -d- -f1 | sed 's/\.//g')
```

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь, заранее спасибо

Comment: А сколько всего строчек? Задача - всегда считывать попарно? "по кругу" - значит сначала или следую\ие две строчки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

`$ ls -1`

```
data.txt
doit.sh
```

`$ cat data.txt`

```
send Helloworld
wait 3
```

`$ cat doit.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
param=$(awk 'NR == 1{ print$2 }' data.txt)   # считываем параметр запуска
timeout=$(awk 'NR == 2{ print$2 }' data.txt) # считываем задержку
echo "$param" && sleep "$timeout" && "$0"    # выполняем программу echo с параметром "Helloworld" и задержкой "3"
```

Вариант 2

`$ cat doit.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
eval $(echo `< data.txt` | awk '{ print "param="$2";timeout="$4 }')
echo "$param" && sleep "$timeout" && "$0"    # выполняем программу echo с параметром "Helloworld" и задержкой "3", $0 - повторный запуск скрипта
```

Comment: не прще ли всё в awk?

Comment: @0xdb, да, действительно, подправил ))

Comment: Я имeл ввиду - `eval $(awk ' blahbla ...; print param; print timeout')` - т.е. всё,  зачем два вызова.

Comment: @0xdb, можно подробнее? Не знаком с такой конструкцией.

Comment: Попробуйте - `eval $(awk ' { /*do something*/ } END { print "args=-c timeout=3"; }' </dev/null); echo $args $timeout`

Comment: Добавил второй вариант. Но, по-моему, менее читаемый.

Comment: Почему не читаемый? Echo лишнее. Логика отсутствует, потому что автор не ответил, и мы не знаем как выглядит файлик с данными.

Comment: `echo` не лишнее, без `echo` вывод другой.